# Leaflet: Open street Map server down?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

Anyone having problems to display Open street Map on leaflet?

Seems like the server is been down for two days?

```
var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup(); // NOTE: Layer is created here!

            var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> ',
                maxZoom: 18
            });

            var cartodb_light = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a> ',
                maxZoom:18
            });
```

My ESRI layer does display but not the OSM? Anyone knows whats going on? It seems i cannot display the standard map on the website also... ?

Comment: OpenStreetMap website uses the exact same tiles: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/48.8403/2.3198 Works fine for me right now.

Comment: Im in Vietnam... Might me down here... Goverment maybe...

Comment: There are lots of OSM-based tile servers available. Maybe you can find a working one here: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/. Also think about switching `http` to `https`.